# mvn: command not found - terminal

Tags: spring, maven, terminal

I am using a Mac Pro machine and want to install maven. So here is what I am doing. First I download the appropriate .zip. I unzip it and in terminal I type

```
Theodosioss-MacBook-Pro:~ theo$ export M2_HOME=/Users/theo/apache- 
maven-3.5.4
```

and

```
Theodosioss-MacBook-Pro:~ theo$ export 
PATH=$PATH:/Users/theodosiostziomakas/apache-maven-3.5.4
```

Then I check if maven is installed but I get this.

```
mvn --version
-bash: mvn: command not found
```

How to properly fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to add `maven` path to your `PATH` variable correctly,as others have said

```
export PATH=/YOUR_LOCAL_LOCATION/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin:$PATH
```

then you need to call `source /etc/profile`(pay attention to check the user type,`root` or no `root`) to make it into effect and then open a new terminal for test

Comment: This works partially for me but when I close the terminal and type mvn -version it can't find it. How do you make it permanent?

Comment: thanks tried that, still did not save it, so ended up using homebrew which solved it

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/theodosiostziomakas/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin
```

mvn executable is inside bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

You have not indicated proper dir, try as below

```
export PATH=/YOUR_LOCAL_LOCATION/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me. 
Changes are done to .bash - .profile did not work on my mac

Update the config in `~/.profile`

```
export M2_HOME=<PATH>/apache-maven-X.Y>Z
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```